# How to make several links between two nodes (java)

Tags: java, dictionary, hyperlink, nodes, edges

Im trying to write a code where you select two nodes and create one or several connections between them. The problem is i can only create one connection, the connection consists of a to-edge and a from-edge,  im using a listedge inside a hashmap.

The problem is i cant figure out how to make several links between two nodes, it only registers one link.
Any advice how i can make it so it register several links? Do i need to create another map?

```
public class ListGraph<G> implements Graph<G> {
private Map<G, List<ListEdge<G>>> nodes = new HashMap<G, List<ListEdge<G>>>();

public void addNode(G ny) {
    if (!nodes.containsKey(ny))
        nodes.put(ny, new ArrayList<ListEdge<G>>());
}

public void connect(G from, G to, String name, int weight) {
        getEdgesFrom(from).add(new ListEdge<G>(to, weight, name));
        getEdgesFrom(to).add(new ListEdge<G>(from, weight, name));      
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

When you `add` to a Map, if the key is found the value is replaced with the new one.

What you must do is.

1) Find if the key is already (check if `get()` return `null` or an `ListEdge<G>`)

2) If it is null, you just `add` as you do in your code.

3) If it is not null, you retrieve the List **and add the new item to the list**, not to the map. So, now you have a key `G` that points to a `ListEdge` with more than one element.

Comment: could this be correct?

`public void addEdges(G from, G to,  String name, int weight){
  
if (getEdge(from, to)!=null){
   getEdgesFrom(from).add(new ListEdge<G>(to, weight, name));
   getEdgesFrom(to).add(new ListEdge<G>(from, weight, name));  
  }
   else return;  
 }`

(sorry i dont know how to edit it correctly)

Comment: It would be nice if you showed the code for `getEdge()` in your question (I assume `getEdgesFrom()` and `getEdgesTo()` will be similar).

Comment: Here it is

`public ListEdge<G> getEdge(G from, G to) {
  if (!nodes.containsKey(to))
   throw new NoSuchElementException("Ingen sådan nod!");
  for (ListEdge<G> edge : getEdgesFrom(from))
   if (edge.getDestination() == to)
    return edge;
  return null;
 }`

Comment: You cannot compare object with `==`, use `equals()` instead. For the rest, your new code does not do nothing if `getEdge(from,to)` returns null. It may be okey only if all `(from, to)` pairs are initialized with an empty list at the beginning.